# libc++のビルド時に "cxxabi.h: No such file or directory" エラーになってしまう

Tags: c++, linux, build

libc++をビルドしようとしているのですがうまくできません。
libc++をビルドするためのlibc++abiのビルドは下記の質問の通りに行いました。

[libc++abiをLinuxでビルドしようとしたができない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57877/libcabi%e3%82%92linux%e3%81%a7%e3%83%93%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89%e3%81%97%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84/57881#57881)

その後、libc++のビルドを試みていますが、sudo makeで下記のようなエラーが発生しビルドできません。

cxxabi.hが存在してないと言われています。

私はlibc++abiから初めて、libc++、clangを一通り自前でビルドしたいと考えています。
どうすればよいのでしょうか?

cmakeコマンド:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
    -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI=libcxxabi \
    -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI_INCLUDE_PATHS=/home/username/opt/include \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/username/opt" ../
```

(/home/username/optにlibc++abiをinstallしてある)

エラー内容:

```
/home/yuya/llvm_build/llvm-project/libcxx/src/exception.cpp:14:12: fatal error: cxxabi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <cxxabi.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cxx_shared.dir/build.make:167: src/CMakeFiles/cxx_shared.dir/exception.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:455: src/CMakeFiles/cxx_shared.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: 既知あるいは見当違いかもしれませんが、これらは参考になりますか？ [【2018年11月版】コンパイラ基盤LLVM+Clangをゼロからコンパイル／ビルドする（AWS + CentOS7）。](https://qiita.com/YuukiMiyoshi/items/007bad9857ef0c0fa99a), [LLVMのビルドについてまとめてみる](http://mcommit.hatenadiary.com/entry/2018/01/05/025802), [Ubuntu / Debianに最新のClangをインストールする方法](https://www.mikunimaru.com/entry/2019/06/02/022510), [ソースパッケージ: llvm-toolchain-8 (1:8.0.1-3build1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ja/source/eoan/llvm-toolchain-8)

Comment: エラーと直接は関係ないかもしれませんが、インストール先がユーザーディレクトリ以下 (`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/username/opt"`) であるなら、`make`コマンドは`sudo`での実行は不要かと思います。root権限が必要な場面でのみ使う様に心がけましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cxxabi.h` は `GNU CC` の [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) に付属のヘッダなので `clang`/`llvm` には付属していないような気がします。

`cygwin@winXP32bit` では `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/cxxabi.h`
`gcc-8.3.0@hppa2.0w-hp-hpux11.11` では `/usr/local/include/c++/8.3.0/cxxabi.h`
にありましたのでまず間違いないでしょう。

その `libc++` は `clang` だけでコンパイルできる代物であるか確認済みですか？ もしかしたら `GNU CC` であればコンパイルできるのかもしれません（追加で `GNU binutils` が必要になる可能性大）

`GNU CC` の配布ファイルから `cxxabi.h` だけ持ってきても動く気がしない（中で `GNU CC` 固有と思われるいろんな別ヘッダを使っている）ので `GNU CC` の `./configure` あたりから一式インストールする必要があるかもしれないです。

Comment: gccのヘッダーファイルを指定するばあいの-DLIBCXX_CXX_ABIの値はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか? libcxxabiでよいのでしょうか?

Comment: cxxabi.hのエラーは治ったのですが、<bits/c++config.h>がないというエラーが発生しました。`locate bits/c++config.h`をしてみると`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/c++config.h`と出たので、-DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI_INCLUDE_PATHSに追加してみましたが、bits/c++config.hのエラーは解決されませんでした。